# Project a box from world to image plane

Tags: camera, computer-vision, homography, camera-matrix

I have a calibrated camera with extrinsincs and intrinsics parameters such that I can project a visible point in the world back to the image.

But I need to be able to deal with points that are also outside of what the camera can see.

1. how can I know if a point is visible by the camera? That would solve the issue when dealing with only one point.
2. how can I project a possibly only partially visible 3d box (8 points) back to the image?

My knowledge is limited and I cannot use a 3rd party framework to this end, rather need to implement it in python/C.

Comment: Can't you just project the point into image space and see if it returns a valid pixel value (something in the range of your image size)?

Comment: Let's say that I have 2 points, one of them is in range and the other one is not. How do I draw the segment connecting this 2 points?

Comment: learn about what a "frustum" is in the context of computer *graphics*. you will encounter a 4x4 projection matrix.